# where to put redirect() for all modules of an application

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, generator

In a symfony application, I have a list of modules which are built on the doctrine admin generator. Because the app is embedded in another system I need to replace all redirect() calls in the action class (from sfAction.class.php)   I can paste this in every module, but is there a central place I could use?

Original redirect (symfony/lib/action/sfACtion.class.php)

```
public function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302)
{
// compatibility with url_for2() style signature
if (is_object($statusCode) || is_array($statusCode))
{
  $url = array_merge(array('sf_route' => $url), is_object($statusCode) ? array('sf_subject' => $statusCode) : $statusCode);
  $statusCode = func_num_args() >= 3 ? func_get_arg(2) : 302;
}

$this->getController()->redirect($url, 0, $statusCode);

throw new sfStopException();
```

}

my change

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302){
    if (is_object($statusCode) || is_array($statusCode)){
        $url = array_merge(array('sf_route' => $url), is_object($statusCode) ? array('sf_subject' => $statusCode) : $statusCode);
        $statusCode = func_num_args() >= 3 ? func_get_arg(2) : 302;
    }

    if (is_array($url)){
        $use_url = $this->getController()->genUrl($url, true);
    }else if (substr($url,0,1) == '@'){
        $use_url = $this->getController()->genUrl($url, true);
    }else{
        $use_url = $url;
    }
    $url = NZGBCTools::makeUriJoomlaCompatible($use_url);       

    $this->getController()->redirect($url, 0, $statusCode);

    throw new sfStopException();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class, that extends sfActions, and make your action classes extend that. This way you'll have the central place you need.

Comment: Thanks, that'll work, I was looking for a "symfony place", but this'll work for me.

Comment: This is the "symfony place" as much as it can be. Many things can be done easily via extending a symfony base class. For an awesome example, see http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing